# Javascript - Remove \r\n

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to remove line breaks from content. This syntax doesn't seem to be working. Any ideas?

```
result.response.docs[j].description.substring(0,100).replace(/"\r\n"/g,"")
```

Comment: working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/bvc3d/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
/"\r\n"/g
```

should be

```
/\r\n/g
```

assuming you want to remove all occurrences of `\r\n` and not `\r` and `\n` individually.

If you want to remove all newline characters, you should be using `/\r|\n/g`.

Answer (score 1):

Try the regex a bit differently. You don't need the quotation marks in your expression, just the carriage return and new line characters themselves:

```
result.response.docs[j].description.substring(0,100).replace(/\r\n/g, '');
```